# How do you tweak iptables limit rules on openSUSE Tumbleweed?

Tags: iptables, logs, opensuse, firewall, multicast

I have a fresh install of openSUSE Tumbleweed, it is logging a lot firewall related stuff due to my apple devices multicasting to enable airplay.

Lines look like:

```
Mar 14 12:45:13 server kernel: SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:fb:98:d6:bb:20:90:a2:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:189b:b08a:4ad3:89bf DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:00fb LEN=271 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=30502 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=231 
Mar 14 12:46:48 server kernel: SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:fb:f0:24:75:e4:6e:54:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1c6a:034e:81fc:bb59 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:00fb LEN=124 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=899138 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=84
```

There are three *(one in this specific example, since proto=udp)* iptables definitions that can cause these log lines to be created:

```
# iptables -S | grep SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p icmp -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p udp -m limit --limit 3/min -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
```

I have three airplay receivers and a bunch of airplay clients on this network, so three connections per minute is probably less than expected.

I'd like to tweak the rule and change `3/min` to `10/min` or something similar just to stop filling up the logs with non sense, but I am unable to find where these lines are defined.

When I look at the firewall settings in `yast2` there is no trace of limit settings.

How do I go about changing this limit?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know where the source of the rules is on openSUSE but WRT your problem: IMO a better idea would be to do a more specific match on the problem sources.  If some local device is spewing broadcast messages, create a rule to target it specifically (e.g. `-s 192.168.0.0/22` or `-d 255.255.255.255` and `-m multiport` with the ports) then just `-j DROP` (`REJECT`ing a broadcast packet won't stop the sender anyway).  Then that stuff is filtered out before the `-j LOG` rules.

Comment: Reached the same conclusion myself, assigned the interface to the local zone and that circumvented the logging rules. As you stated it does not answer the question, but it do solve the problem of the logs filling up. ;)